# Real time Linux: disable local timer interrupts

Tags: timer, linux-kernel, real-time, scheduler, interrupt

***TL;DR*** : Using Linux kernel real time with NO_HZ_FULL I need to isolate a process in order to have deterministic results but /proc/interrupts tell me there is still local timer interrupts (among other). How to disable it?

***Long version :***

I want to make sure my program is not being interrupt so I try to use a real time Linux kernel.
I'm using the real time version of arch Linux (linux-rt on AUR) and I modified the configuration of the kernel to selection the following options :

```
CONFIG_NO_HZ_FULL=y
CONFIG_NO_HZ_FULL_ALL=y
CONFIG_RCU_NOCB_CPU=y
CONFIG_RCU_NOCB_CPU_ALL=y
```

then I reboot my computer to boot on this real time kernel with the folowing options:

```
nmi_watchdog=0
rcu_nocbs=1
nohz_full=1
isolcpus=1
```

I also disable the following option in the BIOS :

```
C state
intel speed step
turbo mode
VTx
VTd
hyperthreading
```

My CPU (i7-6700 3.40GHz) has 4 cores (8 logical CPU with hyperthreading technology)
I can see CPU0, CPU1, CPU2, CPU3 in /proc/interrupts file.

CPU1 is isolated by `isolcpus` kernel parameter and I want to disable the local timer interrupts on this CPU.
I though real-time kernel with CONFIG_NO_HZ_FULL and CPU isolation (isolcpus) was enough to do it and I try to check by running theses command :

```
cat /proc/interrupts | grep LOC > ~/tmp/log/overload_cpu1
taskset -c 1 ./overload
cat /proc/interrupts | grep LOC >> ~/tmp/log/overload_cpu1
```

where the overload process is:

```
***overload.c:***
int main()
{
  for(int i=0;i<100;++i)
    for(int j=0;j<100000000;++j);
}
```

The file `overload_cpu1` contains the result:

```
LOC:     234328        488      12091      11299   Local timer interrupts
LOC:     239072        651      12215      11323   Local timer interrupts
```

meanings 651-488 = 163 interrupts from local timer and not 0...

For comparison I do the same experiment but I change the core where my process `overload` run (I keep watching interrupts on CPU1):

```
taskset -c 0 :   8 interrupts
taskset -c 1 : 163 interrupts
taskset -c 2 :   7 interrupts
taskset -c 3 :   8 interrupts
```

One of my question is why there is no 0 interrupts ? why the number of interrupts is bigger when my process run on CPU1 ? (I mean I though NO_HZ_FULL will prevent interrupt if my process was alone : "The CONFIG_NO_HZ_FULL=y Kconfig option causes the kernel to avoid
sending scheduling-clock interrupts to CPUs with a single runnable task"(https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/timers/NO_HZ.txt)

Maybe an explaination is there is other process running on CPU1.
I checked by using ps command :

```
CLS CPUID RTPRIO PRI  NI CMD                           PID
TS      1      -  19   0 [cpuhp/1]                      18
FF      1     99 139   - [migration/1]                  20
TS      1      -  19   0 [rcuc/1]                       21
FF      1      1  41   - [ktimersoftd/1]                22
TS      1      -  19   0 [ksoftirqd/1]                  23
TS      1      -  19   0 [kworker/1:0]                  24
TS      1      -  39 -20 [kworker/1:0H]                 25
FF      1      1  41   - [posixcputmr/1]                28
TS      1      -  19   0 [kworker/1:1]                 247
TS      1      -  39 -20 [kworker/1:1H]                501
```

As you can see, there is threads on the CPU1.
Is that possible to disable these processes ? I guess it is because if it is not the case, NO_HZ_FULL will never work right ?

Tasks with class TS doesn't disturb me because they didn't have priority among SCHED_FIFO and I can set this policy to my program.
Same things for tasks with class FF and priority less than 99.

However, you can see migration/1 that is in SCHED_FIFO and priority 99.
Maybe these process can causes interrupts when they run . This explain the few interrupts when my process in on CPU0, CPU2 and CPU3 (respectively 8,7 and 8 interrupts) but it also mean these processes are not running very often and then doesn't explain why there is many interrupts when my process run on CPU1 (163 interrupts).

I also do the same experiment but with the SCHED_FIFO of my overload process and I get:

```
taskset -c 0 : 1
taskset -c 1 : 4063
taskset -c 2 : 1
taskset -c 3 : 0
```

In this configuration there is more interrupts in the case my process use SCHED_FIFO policy on CPU1 and less on other CPU. do you know why ?

Comment: I've come across the issue before in the past. If I recall, the problem stems from inter-core communication within to the Intel processors I was using -- the interrupt functionality is built-in to the hardware itself and not configurable from software.

It didn't matter what configuration I set for Linux, the issue was not a kernel scheduling problem, but rather inherent in my hardware; I could run FreeDOS and still see the SMI interrupts. Ultimately we decided to utilize an FPGA to achieve our deterministic requirements -- though understandably that may not suit your needs.

Comment: yes your answer doesn't solve my problem but it is still good to know. Thank you for that.
SMI are indeed non maskable interrupts so I guess they are include in "NMI" line of /proc/interrupts and I'm lucky because I haven't so much of theses interrupts. 
However Local timer interrupts should not be in NMI.
I also experiment some strange results on timing. I need to continue my tests and later I will probably create a new question because I think it is not really related to local timers interrupts.

Comment: AFAIK, while SMI interrupts are non maskable, NMI and SMI are two separate things.  I think the SMI interrupt is completely transparent to the OS and not in any of these counters.

Comment: Did you config your `RT throttling`( /proc/sys/kernel/sched_rt_period_us), which prevents your RT tasks from completely occupying the core and staving other non-RT tasks. Theoretically, no LOC would occur when an RT task with 99 priority is running and doesn't give up the core voluntarily.

Answer (score 6):

The thing is that a full-tickless CPU (a.k.a. adaptive-ticks, configured with `nohz_full=`) still receives some ticks.

Most notably the scheduler requires a timer on an isolated full tickless CPU for updating some state every second or so.

This is a documented limitation (as of 2019):

> Some process-handling operations still require the occasional
>       scheduling-clock tick.  These operations include calculating CPU
>       load, maintaining sched average, computing CFS entity vruntime,
>       computing avenrun, and carrying out load balancing.  They are
>       currently accommodated by scheduling-clock tick every second
>       or so.  On-going work will eliminate the need even for these
>       infrequent scheduling-clock ticks.

(source: [Documentation/timers/NO_HZ.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/timers/NO_HZ.txt), cf. the LWN article [(Nearly) full tickless operation in 3.10](https://lwn.net/Articles/549580/) from 2013 for some background)

A more accurate method to measure the local timer interrupts (LOC row in `/proc/interrupts`) is to use `perf`. For example:

```
$ perf stat -a -A -e irq_vectors:local_timer_entry ./my_binary
```

Where `my_binary` has threads pinned to the isolated CPUs that non-stop utilize the CPU without invoking syscalls - for - say 2 minutes.

There are other sources of additional local timer ticks (when there is just 1 runnable task).

For example, the collection of VM stats - by default they are collected each seconds. Thus, I can decrease my LOC interrupts by setting a higher value, e.g.:

```
# sysctl vm.stat_interval=60
```

Another source are periodic checks if the TSC on the different CPUs doesn't drift - you can disable those with the following kernel option:

```
tsc=reliable
```

(Only apply this option if you really know that your TSCs don't drift.)

You might find other sources by recording traces with [ftrace](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt) (while your test binary is running).

Since it came up in the comments: Yes, the SMI is fully transparent to the kernel. It doesn't show up as NMI. You can only detect an SMI indirectly.