# Disable timer interrupt on Linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, centos, real-time

I want to disable the timer interrupt on some of the cores (1-2) on my machine which is a x86 running centos 7 with rt patch, both cores are isolated cores with `nohz_full`, (you can see the cmdline) but timer interrupt continues to interrupt the real time process which are running on core1 and core2.

```
1. uname -r
3.10.0-693.11.1.rt56.632.el7.x86_64

2. cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-693.11.1.rt56.632.el7.x86_64 \
   root=/dev/mapper/centos-root ro crashkernel=auto \
   rd.lvm.lv=centos/root rd.lvm.lv=centos/swap rhgb quiet \ 
   default_hugepagesz=2M hugepagesz=2M hugepages=1024 \
   intel_iommu=on isolcpus=1-2 irqaffinity=0 intel_idle.max_cstate=0 \
   processor.max_cstate=0 idle=mwait tsc=perfect rcu_nocbs=1-2 rcu_nocb_poll \
   nohz_full=1-2 nmi_watchdog=0

 3. cat /proc/interrupts
           CPU0       CPU1       CPU2
  0:         29          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      timer
.....
......

NMI:          0          0          0   Non-maskable interrupts
LOC:  835205157  308723100  308384525   Local timer interrupts
SPU:          0          0          0   Spurious interrupts
PMI:          0          0          0   Performance monitoring interrupts
IWI:          0          0          0   IRQ work interrupts
RTR:          0          0          0   APIC ICR read retries
RES:  347330843  309191325  308417790   Rescheduling interrupts
CAL:          0        935        935   Function call interrupts
TLB:        320         22         58   TLB shootdowns
TRM:          0          0          0   Thermal event interrupts
THR:          0          0          0   Threshold APIC interrupts
DFR:          0          0          0   Deferred Error APIC interrupts
MCE:          0          0          0   Machine check exceptions
MCP:          2          2          2   Machine check polls
```

CPUs/Clocksource:

```
4. lscpu | grep CPU.s
CPU(s):                3
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-2
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-2

5. cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource
tsc
```

Thanks a lot for any help.
Moses

Comment: There is a lot of interesting data and wishes, but no question that I can see.   If your question is “Why am I getting so many timer interrupts on cores [12]?”, then my first question back is “Are your real time processes using timers?”.

Comment: this is my question indeed, my real-time process don't use timer or system call (only at the init of the process) and the timer interrupt continue to arrive ?

Comment: Related question: [Real time linux : disable local timer interrupts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46077582/real-time-linux-disable-local-timer-interrupts) and on UNIX stackexchange: [Do kernel threads seem to interfere with full tickless mode?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134733/do-kernel-threads-seem-to-interfere-with-full-tickless-mode)

Answer (score 3):

Even with `nohz_full=` you get some ticks on the isolated CPUs:

> Some process-handling operations still require the occasional scheduling-clock tick. These operations include calculating CPU load, maintaining sched average, computing CFS entity vruntime, computing avenrun, and carrying out load balancing. They are currently accommodated by scheduling-clock tick every second or so. On-going work will eliminate the need even for these infrequent scheduling-clock ticks.
>   ([Documentation/timers/NO_HZ.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/timers/NO_HZ.txt), cf. [(Nearly) full tickless operation in 3.10](https://lwn.net/Articles/549580/) LWN, 2013)

Thus, you have to check the rate of the local timer, e.g.:

```
$ perf stat -a -A -e irq_vectors:local_timer_entry sleep 120
```

(while your isolated threads/processes are running)

Also, `nohz_full=` is only effective if there is just one runnable task on each isolated core. You can check that with e.g. `ps -L -e -o pid,tid,user,state,psr,cmd` and `cat /proc/sched_debug`.

Perhaps you need to move some (kernel) tasks to you house-keeping core, e.g.:

```
# tuna -U -t '*' -c 0-4 -m
```

You can get more insights into what timers are still active by looking at `/proc/timer_list`.

Another method to investigate causes for possible interruption is to use the functional tracer ([ftrace](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt)). See also [Reducing OS jitter due to per-cpu kthreads](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-per-CPU-kthreads.txt) for some examples.

I see `nmi_watchdog=0` in your kernel parameters, but you don't disable the soft watchdog. Perhaps this is another timer tick source that would show up with ftrace.

You can disable all watchdogs with `nowatchdog`.

Btw, some of your kernel parameters seem to be off:

- `tsc=perfect` - do you mean `tsc=reliable`? The 'perfect' value isn't documented in the kernel docs
- `idle=mwait` - do you mean `idle=poll`? Again, I can't find the 'mwait' value in the kernel docs
- `intel_iommu=on` - what's the purpose of this?

Comment: The `idle=mwait` option exists in kernels earlier than v3.9-rc1. The `irqaffinity` parameter specifies a list of CPUs, not a mask. So `irqaffinity=0` says that CPU 0 should handle the interrupts. The `tsc=perfect` is a proposed parameter, but was never accepted in the upstream kernel. The `tuna` tool is only supported on RHEL and Arch Linux, I think. I don't think any of the four parameters you mentioned are relevant. The OP probably just wanted to show that `nohz_full` was set in the kernel command line.

Comment: @HadiBrais `tuna` is also available on Fedora and Debian. I can confirm that it works fine on Fedora. Ok, `irqaffinity` takes a cpu list. Well, `tsc=` and `idle=` are relevant when you want to minimize OS jitter. For example, without `tsc=reliable` the kernel periodically checks if the TSC is still reliable.

Comment: For those that want to use `irqaffinity` to move everything off CPU 0 at boot, the kernel is hardcoded to force the use of the first CPU, commenting out the following removes this: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/458ef2a25e0cbdc216012aa2b9cf549d64133b08/kernel/irq/irqdesc.c#L36 (use at your own peril)