# Completely eliminating the timer tick in modern Linux >=5.0

Tags: linux, timer, linux-kernel, real-time, interrupt

I'm trying to completely eliminate timer interrupts on a set of cores on a quiet machine. These are the only interrupts regularly processed by these cores. I've `isolcpu`'d them, and built a kernel with `CONFIG_NO_HZ_FULL`, and indeed now they only receive timer interrupts around once a second. **Is it possible to remove this residual 1Hz timer interrupt?**

This [kernel doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/timers/NO_HZ.txt) suggests that an occasional tick was necessary at some point:

> Some process-handling operations still require the occasional
>       scheduling-clock tick.  These operations include calculating CPU
>       load, maintaining sched average, computing CFS entity vruntime,
>       computing avenrun, and carrying out load balancing.  They are
>       currently accommodated by scheduling-clock tick every second
>       or so.  On-going work will eliminate the need even for these
>       infrequent scheduling-clock ticks.

And this [kernel patch](https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/876869/), "Remove the 1 Hz tick code," suggests that it was removed in a later version of the kernel:

> Now that the 1Hz tick is offloaded to workqueues, we can safely remove
>   the residual code that used to handle it locally.

I've built the 5.3.0 kernel hoping that this residual tick would be removed, but it's still present.

Are there additional boot parameters I need to set? Is the residual timer tick really removed in the latest versions of the kernel? ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46077582/real-time-linux-disable-local-timer-interrupts) has some relevant information)

Comment: If you're asking how to configure your kernel build, that's not a programming question.  I think it's probably on-topic over at [unix.se].

Comment: I read that as the 1 Hz tick code being offloaded to the global workqueue, not removed entirely. The commit description for [sched/isolation: Offload residual 1Hz scheduler tick](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=d84b31313ef8a8de55a2cbfb72f76f36d8c927fb) provides more information.

Comment: @TobySpeight the question I linked is very similar and has not been closed/has 6 upvotes, and there are plenty of other SO questions about configuring Linux. I also think SO is a reasonable place to reach people with kernel dev experience, who might have some insights here.

Comment: @sevko did the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 1HZ tick can't be removed completely from all cpus otherwise we won't be able to keep any statistics. Instead what happens is that it is now run through a workqueue and you can now configure a `housekeeping` CPU that will handle all global workqueue tasks. See this [commit](https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/888867/) for details.

It is also recommended to use nohz_full command-line parameter along with cpusets to manage the set of isolated cpus. You still need to let one of them (boot CPU by default) to be the housekeeping cpu.

Comment: I'm currently running with `isolcpus=8-15 nohz_full=8-15` and ran `echo 1 > /sys/devices/virtual/workqueue/cpumask`, but the residual 1Hz tick still runs on core 13 for example. Looks like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55061939/how-to-offload-the-1hz-tick-in-dyntick-mode) had similar difficulties. Trying to figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: `nohz_offload` seems relevant but isn't in the 5.3.0 kernel parameters documentation.

Comment: Got it to work. My final set of kernel parameters was `isolcpus=nohz,domain,8-15 nohz_full=8-15`. Moreover, I realized that I was running my program with FIFO scheduling via `chrt -f` but forgot to set `/proc/sys/kernel/sched_rt_runtime_us` to -1, which introduced variability (probably because it was getting preempted by the kernel). Both running without `chrt -f`, or running with it but setting `sched_rt_runtime_us` to -1, fixed the problem.

Comment: @sevko I found that I didn't need the nohz_full= (I think it's redundant given the isolcpus=nohz) but I had to add tsc=reliable, on CentOS 8 with kernel 4.18.